# How to calculate value at risk in accordance with Basel?

Tags: value-at-risk, banks, basel, market-risk

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know whether Value at Risk should be calculated for net open position (foreign currency assets-foreign currency liabilities) or for foreign currency cash?

Could you please introduce me a book regarding Value at Risk measurement in accordance with Basel (including numerical examples)? I already read [it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133456315).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is no 'right' approach. Bank authorities like to see that your calculations have a sufficient degree of conservatism.

To summarize, you can apply the following:

1. If you calculate VaR to the **gross** positions (asset or liabilities) and add them up, you mostly end up with a higher VaR which implicates a higher need for economic capital to be reserved.
2. If you calculate VaR to the **net** position, you implicitly assume some portfolio level, which might include diversification effects. This results mostly in a lower VaR (i.e. less economic capital to be reserved), but since this approach is 'less conservative' you have additional effort to proof the stability of the underlying diversification effects.

edit: for numerical examples, see e.g. this [one](https://www.amazon.de/Market-Risk-Analysis-Models-Finance/dp/0470997885)